# texstudio scripting:converting selected text

Tags: texstudio

There is not ToUppercase ToLowercase function which convers text in my language from
so called small letters to capital letters.

how can i loop char by char in selected text in texstudio to convert selected text?
example:
from_array={'ა','ბ','გ','დ'}
to_array={'Ⴀ','Ⴁ','Ⴂ','Ⴃ'}

need to replace seelcted text from from_array to to_array

Comment: The upcoming version 2.7.0 has functions `Edit -> Text Operations -> To Uppercase` (also lowercase). You can try them (either in the current 2.7.0 beta version or you wait till the official release this week).

Comment: that feature works for English no for text i'm using/Georgian/. Modern georgian is assumed caseless. But I need often to convert from one script to another. such regex example for TexStudio would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can write a User Script if you need more control than the builtin `Edit -> Textoperations`. See these examples

- [Convert selected text to uppercase](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Scripts#Convert_selected_text_to_uppercase)
- [Replace characters by their LaTeX equivalent while typing](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Scripts#Replace_characters_by_their_LaTeX_equivaltent_while_typing)

Comment: Yes i know i use my several macros. Dont know how to make "Replace in selected text" not during typing :(